# present and future continuous + conditional mood sentence correction

Tags: conditional-constructions

If I say this:

> If I am sleeping when he will be coming wake me up, please.

Will it be correct phrase or I should say another way?

Comment: Please see when in this dictionary: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/question-words/when [same in American English by the way].

Comment: If I'm asleep when he arrives, please wake me up.

Comment: I'm sleeping is OK too.

Comment: Right, the only problem is **will be coming**.

Answer (score 0):

> If I am sleeping when he will be coming wake me up, please.

Don't use this. It means "He is not here. He is coming. Wake me up." For example, if your brother calls your mother and says "I will be home on Saturday," you want your mother to come and wake you immediately, even if it is Monday!

If you *do* want to say that, use:

> If you find out when he is coming while I'm sleeping, wake me up, please.

But as the commenters pointed out, what you probably want is:

> **If he arrives while I'm sleeping, please wake me up.**

Or perhaps:

> **Please wake me up before he gets here, if I'm sleeping.**

Which implies you want a warning so you have enough time to get ready.